# How to make requests not decode percent escapes in my url?

Tags: python, python-requests, url-encoding

I'm trying to get website content with requests lib.
but I have to use one encoded char (`m` as `%6D`)

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
profile_id=321321
user_profile_url = 'http://nodomain.com/?%6Dodule=' + str(profile_id)
user_profile = session.get(user_profile_url)
print(user_profile.text)
```

how can I send this without requests decoding the `%6D` back into an `m`?

Comment: Is this also your question, posted with a different user? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630718/

Answer (score 2):

The URLs

```
http://nodomain.com/?%6Dodule=321321
http://nodomain.com/?module=321321
```

are equivalent according to RFC 3986. It does not matter if you encode the character "m" or not.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.2.2

Comment: Yes, but some websites may handle them differently for whatever reason.

Comment: Then these websites are violating the RFC, which causes all sorts of problems, like the one you have. Even if the client could be changed to encode the "m" character unnecessarily, intermediate components (such as proxies, reverse proxies, web server modules, etc.) may remove the unnecessary encoding, which is usually outside the control of the developer (you), the user or the server admin.

Comment: I just wanna send the requests "as is".

Comment: Then don't use `requests` - but it still doesn't make sense, as Florian mentions in it's comment anyone on the request path to the destination server is allowed to decode / reencode your url as needed since according to the law (well the RFC that is) both version are strictly the __same__ url.